# Query SqlServer in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have installed Windows PowerShell Extensions for SQL Server 2008 R2

and trying to do the following 
**Add-PsSnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100**
and
**Add-PsSnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100**

but got the following error

> Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.
>   At line:1 char:13
>   + Add-PsSnapin <<<<  sqlserverprovidersnapin100
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (sqlserverprovidersnapin100:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

it is an 32 bit windows 7 machine I am trying to run the powershell on.

thanks.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management studio installed?

Comment: @AndyArismendi SSMS is not required install when you use the extensions package.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just use the command `Add-PSSnapin SQL`. It easier to remember and quicker to type.

I'm guessing you did install all the the prerequisites such as SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects? As stated on the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978) this is required.